# Injecting @angular/router on karma test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-routing

I generated a project with [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and when try to run my tests i get a circular dependency error.

This is how i am including the router module in my test file:

```
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NavbarComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule }, Auth]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I am getting the following error when i run `ng test`:

```
Failed: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Router ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule DynamicTestModule in ./DynamicTestModule@-1:-1


Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Router ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule DynamicTestModule in ./DynamicTestModule@-1:-1
    at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:37690:19)
    at NgModuleCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.NgModuleCompiler.compile (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:44506:36)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:52725:73)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:52684:106
    at Object.then (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:27694:148)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:52681:26)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:52613:37)
    at TestingCompilerImpl.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler/testing.es5.js.TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:54029:31)
    at TestBed.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js.TestBed.compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:69896:31)
    at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js.TestBed.compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:69779:67)
```

Is this a problem with the Router itself?
Should i avoid injecting it?

Comment: You are trying to provide the Router and instruct it to use the RouterModule. That won't work, why not importing the RouterModule ? `imports: [RouterModule]` and maybe better use the `RouterTestingModule` => https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule

Comment: Use the [`RouterTestingModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule), that's what it's for. But as @cyrix notes it should be in `imports` not `providers`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe write an answer an i will makr it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the approach of simply creating a jasmine spy object when dealing with Angular's Router and checking to see if it gets called, since with this approach you can quickly see if it is called with three lines of code to insert into your component:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let router: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    router = jasmine.createSpyObj('router', ['navigate']);
    component = new MyComponent;

  }));
```

A more detailed approach, and closer to the standard is to use a RouterStub, which is described on the [Angular - Testing Guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing) page.

```
class RouterStub {
  navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
}

beforeEach( async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: HeroService, useClass: FakeHeroService },
      { provide: Router,      useClass: RouterStub }
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents().then(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

it('should tell ROUTER to navigate when hero clicked',
  inject([Router], (router: Router) => { // ...

  const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

  heroClick(); // trigger click on first inner <div class="hero">

  // args passed to router.navigateByUrl()
  const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

  // expecting to navigate to id of the component's first hero
  const id = comp.heroes[0].id;
  expect(navArgs).toBe('/heroes/' + id,
    'should nav to HeroDetail for first hero');
}));
```

I know others mentioned this, but if you want to implement anything closer to the full Module instead of a Stub or jasmine spy you'll want to use RouterTestingModule. Normally a jasmine spy or stub is enough to test the component functionality.